# Nginx reverse proxy error - too many redirects

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, certbot

I have set up an Nginx reverse proxy but I am getting an error. I don't know why this is happening, something is wrong with my configuration file.

> This page isn't working - redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Here is my conf file as Certbox generated it

```
server {
    server_name     base.4evergaming.com;
    error_page 403  https://www.4evergaming.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/base.4evergaming.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/base.4evergaming.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = base.4evergaming.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name     base.4evergaming.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this config. Check you app on 192.168.1.10

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyTen It turned out I had to specify ````proxy_pass https://192.168.1.10:443````

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following configuration

```
server {
    server_name     base.4evergaming.com;
    error_page 403  https://www.4evergaming.com;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:80;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/base.4evergaming.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/base.4evergaming.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name     base.4evergaming.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Why would I compare this config with the config given in the question, to find out what changed?  Where is the explanation why this should be _tried_?

Comment: Forwarding https to http in this config